# How to change the download folder destenation in firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing a firefox extension that downloads pictures from the current page in facebook.
I wonder if there is a way to change the default download directory to X. and more preferably to ask the user to input one.
Thanks

Comment: u want to programatic help or what

Comment: yes, I am looking for a method just like saveURL is for saving the file.

Answer (score 1):

This information is stored in the preferences file and can be viewed under `about:config`. If the preference `browser.download.useDownloadDir` is set to `true` the download directory set in `browser.download.dir` is used automatically. If this variable is set to `false` the browser will ask the user where to save the file, with the directory set in `browser.download.lastDir` initially selected in the dialog.

However, if you are writing an extension you probably don't want to use these preference but rather let the user choose a download directory. You would use [nsIFilePicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFilePicker) for that, along these lines:

```js
var filePicker = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"]
                           .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker);
filePicker.init(window, "Please choose a download directory", filePicker.modeGetFolder);
if (filePicker.show() == 0)
  window.alert("Directory chosen: " + filePicker.file.path);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//give your file details in this line
downloadFile(title, url, fileType);

// Don't change anything below if you don't know what it does

function getDownloadFile(defaultString, fileType) 
{
    var nsIFilePicker = Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker;

    var fp = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"].createInstance(nsIFilePicker);
    fp.init(window, "Save As", nsIFilePicker.modeSave);
    try {
        var urlExt = defaultString.substr(defaultString.lastIndexOf(".")+1, 3);
        if (urlExt!=fileType) defaultString += "." + fileType
    }catch(ex){}

    fp.defaultString = defaultString;

    fp.appendFilter(fileType, "*." + fileType);
    var rv = fp.show();
    if (rv == nsIFilePicker.returnOK || rv == nsIFilePicker.returnReplace) {
      var file = fp.file;
      var path = fp.file.path;
      return file;
    }
    return null;
}
function downloadFile(title, url, fileType) 
{
    var file = getDownloadFile(title, fileType);

    var persist = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist);  
    var ios = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);  
    var uri = ios.newURI(url, null, null); 

    var target = ios.newFileURI(file) 
    var xfer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/transfer;1"]  
                           .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransfer);  
    xfer.init(uri, target, "", null, null, null, persist);  
    persist.progressListener = xfer; 
    persist.saveURI(uri, null, null, null, null, file);

}
```