# download a file to particular location in client system

Tags: java, security, file-upload, file-io, download

Below is the code i've written i've to download a file, 
Now I need to download the file to particular location in client system.I'll get the path through input from the  user. 
I know it's not good to mess client system but I had to do that

```
        //setting the content type of response
        response.setContentType("application/"+strFileType);

        response.setHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename="+strFileName+"."+strFileType);

        //creating a file input stream object
         InputStream input = blob.getBinaryStream();

         //declaring a variable
         int i;
         while((i=input.read())!=-1)
         {
             //writing output
             printWriter.write(i);
         }

         //closing the streams
         input.close();
         printWriter.close();
```

Comment: Can't be done from the server. It would be a big security hole.

Comment: seems this is server side code... what you have tried in client side ?

Comment: If you have designed your program in a way that you require this functionality, then you (probably) are either designing malware or have designed your program incorrectly.

Comment: Wait, if you get the path from input from the user, why wouldn't you just use the path provided by the user? :-\.

Comment: where to use the path taken from the user and i'm programming this just like ftp but server side is a database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know it's not good to mess client system but I had to do that ....

Well the good news (*from the user's perspective!*) is that you can't do it.  Even if you "have to".  A web browser is built specifically to stop you (the server side) from doing that kind of thing.

The only away around this is to implement the functionality in a TRUSTED browser plugin or applet or something that the user has to specifically install on his / her machine.

---

> ... where to use the path taken from the user and i'm programming this just like ftp but server side is a database

The problem is that the browser has NO WAY to judge whether you are doing this for legitimate purposes ... or as an attempt to clobber system / user files, plant malware or any number of other things that *may* be harmful to the user.

It ain't going to take the risk of letting you do it, and that is a GOOD THING.

Answer (score 1):

This needs an update of file download location of browser,[**note:** if we update this all files will be download to that path]

refer the below links you may get the idea :

[How to change the download folder destenation in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032760/how-to-change-the-download-folder-destenation-in-firefox)

[How to check the location of download folder programmatically in browsers like Safari, Firefox etc on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006607/how-to-check-the-location-of-download-folder-programmatically-in-browsers-like-s)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6ff178a2-5131-43d4-b4c0-efb4a2112e95

Comment: *"if we update this all files will be download to that path"* Way to 'disenfranchise' the end-user! *"**note:**"* but +1 for 'note'. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside an intranet and can trust a server, use an applet or similar technolofgies with granted access privileges... but once again this is REALLY bad.